# How to set up the HTTP Client to Get XML steps in Pentaho Kettle PDI

Tags: xml, pentaho, tweets, kettle

I would like to find a detailed way of using Kettle PDI 4.2.3 in getting Twitter Search results into a processable format.

What I have up to now is the following steps:

STEP 1:GENERATE ROWS
Here on the first row I insert the link
[Twitter Search Results](http://twitter.com/search/realtime?q=%22I%27m%20at%22%204sq%20colruyt%20OR%20delhaize%20OR%20carrefour%20OR%20mcdonalds%20OR%20quick%20OR%20pizzahut%20OR%20%22pizza%20hut%22%20near%3aBrussels%20within:20km%20since:2012-11-20%20until:2012-11-25%20&src=typd)

Limit=1

STEP 2:HTTP CLIENT
Here I set it up so I get I accept the URL from the previous field. In the Output Fields I write job-xml. In the fields tab I don't know what do do. If I press get fields it will give me the single field from the Generate Row. But I leave it empty.

STEP 3:GET XML DAta
Here is where I have the problem. The current situation is:
-in the File tab I checked Get Xml from a field and I write "job-xml". I leave the rest empty
-in the Content tab Namespace Aware and Do not raise an error if no files qre checked. The Loop XPath is empty. If I press Get XPath Nodes it says "Please provide an XML fragment". Normally it should give me Node options. If I replace the HTTP Client with a Text file Input containing xml code it I get the options for the Nodes.
-in the Fields tab of course I cannot get the fields because it requires me to specify the XPath

So I'm stuck here. Normally I would like to get the Tweeter fields coming from the HTTP Client and then proceed to the next steps like Select Values and an Excel Output.

If someone can figure out what am I doing wrong and can help me get the tweets into excel I would be eternally grateful :)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to write the twitter xml to a file, and then you can use that file for your XML fragment.  It's a bit silly but the get xml stuff where you can pick nodes etc only works when you read the xml from a file.

So setup the Xpath and everything from your file, test it, once it works switch back to xml is in a field.